# Writing jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, function

Im new to Javascript and was wondering how i would write a function (using jQuery) that takes a paramater, and based on that returns different code. I will write the function in PHP so you understand what im trying to do.

```
<?php
  function direction( $l_r )
  {
    if ($l_r == 'left') $dir = '-';
    elseif ($l_r == 'right') $dir = '+';

    echo 'the direction is '. $dir;
    echo '(than theres some more going on here)';
  }
?>
```

Comment: It's less jQuery that you're looking for and just resources on learning JavaScript. jQuery is a framework that is used for DOM manipulation/events. You still write plain old JavaScript with it. Have a look at this question for resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Comment: jQuery is library, not framework. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function direction( l_r )
  {
    var dir;
    if (l_r == 'left') dir = '-';
    else if (l_r == 'right') dir = '+';

    return 'the direction is ' + dir;
  }
```

Comment: try:

`var result =  direction( l_r );`

`$('#module').html( result );`

Comment: @DaveDev - I tried that also, it didnt work. Could it be somethign with the function? I changed one mistake wich was a space in between `else if`. But its still not working...

Comment: @cnotethegr8, that code should work. Could you paste the complete page source you tried?

Comment: @Dogbert - Nevermind, i just noticed you changed the `. dir` into `+ dir`. Works now, thanks!